# Recuperar valor do textarea no form .serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Sempre usei função genérica, mas estou com um problema na recuperação do valor do `textarea`. Utilizo um editor de texto no `textarea`, o **CkEditor**.

Aqui segue a função que estou utilizando:

```
function sendPost(form, action, callback) {
    ajaxRequest == null ? ajaxRequest = null : ajaxRequest.abort();
    if (validateForm($("#" + form))) {
        var msg;
        alert($("#"+form).serialize()); 
        //Utilizei esse alert acima, só para verificar como o POST está indo
        ajaxRequest = $.post("crud/" + action + ".php", $("#" + form).serialize(),
            function (data) {
                dataFromAjaxRequest(data, callback);
            });
    } else {
        $("#dialog_modal_mensagem").dialog("open");
    }
}
```

A saída do `alert`:

```
titulo=teste&data=03%2F04%2F2014&texto=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que atualizar os campos relacionados ao CKEditor, antes de usar o `serialize`:

```
for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
```

Depois disso, o campo do CKEDitor estará preenchido, e deve funcionar.

**Referência:**

[How to ajax-submit a form textarea input from CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256510/how-to-ajax-submit-a-form-textarea-input-from-ckeditor)